# unboundlocalError:local variable 'session' refernced before assignment . "session.add(newItem)"

Tags: python, flask

```
@app.route(
    '/cars/<int:car_shop_id>/menu/new/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def newCar(car_shop_id):
    if 'username' not in login_session:
        return redirect('/login')
        session = connect_to_database()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        newItem = Cars(name=request.form['name'],   
                    description=request.form['description'],
                    price=request.form['price'],
                    car_shop_id=car_shop_id)
        session.add(newItem)
        session.commit()
        flash("Car has been added")
        return redirect(url_for('Car_shopMenu', car_shop_id=car_shop_id))
    else:
        return render_template('newcars.html', car_shop_id=car_shop_id)
```

Comment: No code below a `return` in the same block will ever be executed.

Comment: Your definition of ``session`` is part of the first ``if`` block. Dedent it to the level of the function body.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i think it worked when define of session out if scope but i git a new error : AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'add'

Comment: @YosefHamdy Well, `sqlite3.Connection` doesn't have an ``add`` method. What makes you think it does?

Answer (score 0):

Seems session never get chance to initialize.

```
def newCar(car_shop_id):
    if 'username' not in login_session:
        return redirect('/login')
        session = connect_to_database()
```